# Claim resources/memory from thread single threaded apartment thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, try-catch-finally

I am using following single threaded appartment.
I am unable to reclaim memory/other resources from thread object.
Actullay I want to wrap my thread in try catch and fianlly block.
try and catch are done. But I am unsure about finally block.
What code, property or function do I need to call in finally block.

```
System.Threading.Thread myThread = null;
    try 
    {
        myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(functionAddressETC)
        myThread .SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        myThread .Start();
        myThread .Join();
    }
catch(Exception ex)
{}
finally
{
   // I need help in finally block. I need to reclaim all my resources
   //what function do i need to call here??????
}
```

Comment: What resources are you refering to?  The underlying handle and stack of the thread or the resources that the thread allocates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GC will reclaim memory, finalizers will free native resources. The only way to ensure these processes happen is to ensure that objects you no longer need are unreferenced.

A thread does not have any memory/resources of its own apart from its stack, which will be cleaned up by the Join shutting down the thread (unless you have something messing with duplicating native thread handles: in which case when the last handle is closed).

Comment: you mean i need to check following code in finally block.

finally
{
    if (myThread != null)
    //release code
    //But what function do i need to call here????
}

Comment: You don't have to do anything to cleanup the Thread itself.  You may need to cleanup any unmanaged resources allocated in the thread proc.

Comment: @Syed: The Join is all you need.